# Is there an option to get rustc to show a "successful" message?

Tags: rust

When I compile a program using `rustc` I usually get errors. Once I've eliminated the errors, I get no message which means that compile was successful.

Is there an option to get `rustc` to show a "successful" message? It would be nice to see positive feedback.

Comment: How do you invoke it? (I mean, in Bash, or in Windows command prompt, etc.)

Comment: Do you use Cargo? I found this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/external-tools.html#build-finished (I'm not sure how to use it though, I'm not a Rust user)

Comment: @mkrieger1 rustc file.rs

Comment: What about `rustc file.rs && echo "Success!"`?

Comment: If you start developing non-toy programs and you need multiple calls of the compiler, you will start to appreciate the non-verbose working. Just my 2 cents. Tools telling me that they succeeded are at best bugging me, at worst breaking the development process.

Comment: Cargo outputs "Finished" in bold green text if there are no errors, so this isn't an issue if you use cargo.

Comment: @Aplet123 is there a way to mark your comment as the accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Rust programmers don't invoke `rustc` directly, but instead do it through `cargo`, which prints a green success message for each crate that is compiled:

```sh
$ cargo build
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling bytes v0.5.6
   Compiling mycrate v0.2.0 (/dev/rust/mycrate)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 13.17s
```

You will also get a progress bar tracking the build process:

```sh
$ cargo build
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Building [====================>      ] 3/4: bytes
```

`rustc` is more bare-bones and does not output any success messages. However, you can use `&&` to print a message manually if the compilation was successful:

```sh
$ rustc main.rs && echo "Compiled successfully"
Compiled successfully
```

If you want to get even more fancy, you can use ASCII escape codes to make the message green!

```sh
$ rustc main.rs && echo "\033[0;32mCompiled successfully"
Compiled successfully # <- this is green!
```